# sql server pivot syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I need to do row column transpose and tried a following query

```
select txn_date,
case when remarks is NULL then 'bank' else remarks  end as remarks
 from nibl
  PIVOT
(
count(txn_date)
FOR remarks IN (bank, remit)
) as pivot
```

the query above is giving syntax error as below

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'pivot'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pivot` is a reserved word in SQL Server so it is `) as pivot` that fails here.

Use another alias `) as p`.

Answer (score 0):

did u try it in this way...

```
select * from
(select txn_date,
case when remarks is NULL then 'bank' else remarks  end as remarks
 from nibl
 ) srs
  PIVOT
(
count(txn_date)
FOR remarks IN (bank, remit)
) as pivot
```